# Admob Interstitials In SpriteKit - Swift 3

Tags: swift, xcode, sprite-kit, admob

This question has been asked before but this was quite a while ago and not updated for swift 3 or spritekit.

In my game, once you die, a gameover scene occurs. I would like to be able to present an interstitial ad every 3 times the restart/home button is pressed. Sorry, I am a real beginner and the admob documentation is no help either.

My code for my gameover scene:

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    for touch in touches {
        let location = touch.location(in: self);

        if atPoint(location) == homeButton {
            let homeScene = GameScene(size: self.size)
            let skView = self.view as SKView!
            let myTransition = SKTransition.fade(withDuration: 1)
            skView?.ignoresSiblingOrder = true
            homeScene.scaleMode = .resizeFill
            homeScene.size = (skView?.bounds.size)!
            skView?.presentScene(homeScene, transition: myTransition)

        }

        if atPoint(location) == restartButton {
            let restartScene = PlayScene(size: self.size)
            let skView = self.view as SKView!
            let myTransition = SKTransition.fade(withDuration: 1)
            skView?.ignoresSiblingOrder = true
            restartScene.scaleMode = .resizeFill
            restartScene.size = (skView?.bounds.size)!
            skView?.presentScene(restartScene, transition: myTransition)

        }}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just started using this library for my own app called [SwiftyAds](https://github.com/crashoverride777/SwiftyAds) to help integrate with AdMob.

There is one method in particular that will help you, it is this: `SwiftyAds.shared.showInterstitial(withInterval: 3, from: view?.window?.rootViewController)`

You would put that code where you are detecting the home or restart button. Every 3rd time it is called, the interstitial will show.

Comment: Hi, this sounds cool but how do I install SwiftyAds, I have downloaded the folder from github but I don't know what to do from here. There are quite a few folders! sorry, new to frameworks and libraries!

Comment: The easiest way to do this is to create a new file in your project called SwiftyAds.swift and then add the contents of this file. Here is the direct link to the file: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/crashoverride777/SwiftyAds/master/SwiftyAds/SwiftyAds.swift